# ANTLR Variable Troubles

Tags: antlr, antlr3

**In short: how do I implement dynamic variables in ANTLR?**
I come to you again with a basic ANTLR question.
I have this grammar:

```
grammar Amethyst;

options {
    language = Java;
}

@header {
    package org.omer.amethyst.generated;
    import java.util.HashMap;
}

@lexer::header {
    package org.omer.amethyst.generated;
}

@members {
    HashMap memory = new HashMap();
}

begin: expr;

expr: (defun | println)*
;

println:
    'println' atom {System.out.println($atom.value);}
;

defun:
    'defun' VAR INT {memory.put($VAR.text, Integer.parseInt($INT.text));}
    | 'defun' VAR STRING_LITERAL {memory.put($VAR.text, $STRING_LITERAL.text);}
;

atom returns [Object value]:
    INT {$value = Integer.parseInt($INT.text);}

    |   ID
    {
    Object v = memory.get($ID.text);
    if (v != null) $value = v;
    else System.err.println("undefined variable " + $ID.text);
    }

| STRING_LITERAL
  {
    String v = (String) memory.get($STRING_LITERAL.text);
    if (v != null) $value = String.valueOf(v);
    else System.err.println("undefined variable " + $STRING_LITERAL.text);
  }
;

INT: '0'..'9'+ ;
STRING_LITERAL: '"' .* '"';

VAR: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')* ;
ID: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')+ ;
LETTER: ('a..z'|'A'..'Z')+ ;
WS: (' '|'\t'|'\n'|'\r')+ {skip();} ;
```

What it does (or should do), so far, is have a built-in "println" function to do exactly what you think it does, and a "defun" rule to define variables.
When "defun" is called on either a string or integer, the value is put into the "memory" HashMap with the first parameter being the variable's name and the second being its value.
When println is called on an atom, it should display the atom's value. The atom can be either a string or integer. It gets its value from memory and returns it. So for example:

```
defun greeting "Hello world!"

println greeting
```

But when I run this code, I get this error:

```
line 3:8 no viable alternative at input 'greeting'
null
```

NOTE: This output comes when I do:

```
println "greeting"
```

Output:

```
undefined variable "greeting"null
```

Does anyone know why this is so? Sorry if I'm not being clear, I don't understand most of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> defun greeting "Hello world!"
>
> println greeting
> ```
>
> But when I run this code, I get this error:
>
> line 3:8 no viable alternative at input 'greeting'

Because the input `"greeting"` is being tokenized as a `VAR` and a `VAR` is no `atom`. So the input `defun greeting "Hello world!"` is properly matched by the 2<sup>nd</sup> alternative of the `defun` rule:

```
defun
 : 'defun' VAR INT               // 1st alternative
 | 'defun' VAR STRING_LITERAL    // 2nd alternative
 ;
```

but the input `println "greeting"` cannot be matched by the `println` rule:

```
println
 : 'println' atom
 ;
```

You must realize that the lexer does not produce tokens based on what the parser tries to match at a particular time. The input `"greeting"` will always be tokenized as a `VAR`, never as an `ID` rule.

What you need to do is remove the `ID` rule from the lexer, and replace `ID` with `VAR` inside your parser rules.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. See, I was trying to have ID as any identifier, and VAR as a valid variable name. Thanks!